# Returning to start of script - Which way is best?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Started learning PHP/Javascript by altering example code to display a set of pictures from multiple folders and display the content on a page (this is for artwork from designers to be shown on large 4K monitors in rotation).  I've taken a few days to get the below to work so far (which works fine), but I've been reading around and I think it's my basic knowledge that is causing me to get stuck at this point.  I can't work out how to get the images to display once each (in the jQuery) and then return back to the PHP at the start of the script that enumerates the image folders again.  Would the way forward be to create a loop around the whole PHP / JavaScript script?  Or define them both as functions and have them included in a main script that executes the loop (forever)?

I think it's more about the fact that I don't understand how the jQuery is looping forever, I can see the I increment, but don't get how it's looping the images, rather than getting the number of images and incrementing until it hits the last image.  Any help or explanation or example would be beneficial.

Here's the code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<body bgcolor="#000000">

<Div id="holder">
<img src="team_a/blank.jpg" id="slideshow" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%" />
</Div>
</html>
<?php

// Header("content-type: application/x-javascript"); 

$team_a = array();
$team_1 = array();
$team_2 = array();
$team_3 = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('team_a') as $fileInfo) {
if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
$team_1[] = "team_a".'/'.$fileInfo->getFilename(); // Get file names of Team_A directory
}

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('team_b') as $fileInfo) {
if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
$team_2[] = "team_b".'/'.$fileInfo->getFilename(); // Get file names of Team_B directory
}
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('team_c') as $fileInfo) {
if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
$team_3[] = "team_c".'/'.$fileInfo->getFilename(); // Get file names of Team_C directory
}
$team_a = array_merge_recursive($team_1, $team_2, $team_3); //Merge all the arrays recursively into $team_a

print_r ($team_a); // A quick test of the contents of $team_a
?>
<script = "text/javascript">
var images = <?php echo json_encode($team_a) ?>;
setInterval(forwardImage, 10000);
//This function will find the key for the current Image
function currentImageKey() {
i = jQuery.inArray($('#slideshow').attr('src'), images);
return i;
}
//This function will move the slideshow forward one
function forwardImage() {
currentImageKey();
if (i < images.length - 1) {
    changeImage(i + 1);
} else {
    changeImage(0);
}
}
//This function will change to image to whatever the variable i passes to it
function changeImage(i) {
$('#slideshow').stop().animate({
    opacity: 0,
}, 1000, function() {
    $('#slideshow').attr('src', images[i]);
    $('#holder img').load(function() {
        $('#slideshow').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
        }, 1000)
    })
})
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your line `setInterval(forwardImage, 10000);` is the "infinite timer" function. How frequently are you checking for new images/folders? What would be better for you to use/learn is AJAX. You can make a function that will call your PHP page and have a JSON array returned with your folder/file names and then use Javascript to iterate the returned array and change your pictures. Be careful, too frequent calls to your PHP script will cause a lot of traffic to your webserver...

Comment: Thanks @BigChris ... If I remember rightly, the $team_a array needs to be set as a global variable?

Comment: The folders will never change, just the contents of the folders, so the check would be done once all images have been displayed, the script should just go back and enumerate the contents of the three folders again ...

Comment: I think you should do an initial check on the number of available files -> get these as a JSON and put the count into a Javascript variable -> run a "for" loop of pictures using the count variable -> when the loop is complete re-run the initial check and re-start the loop. Inefficient because it'll re-load the JSON so your request overhead will increase as more and more pictures are added. If your image directories aren't going to change very frequently then I would suggest you just do a single request and when the user refreshes the page (or re-visits later on) do a fresh request.

Comment: The request overhead shouldn't be a problem as these are live feeds to two Sony 4k TVs hanging on walls, only two machines will be displaying the content in a borderless Chrome window.